# Read less than 8k bytes from an HTTP InputStream

Tags: java, http, inputstream

I have a controller class listed below - all it does is (for the sake of demonstrating my issue) generate a number, convert it to a string, convert the string to bytes and write the bytes as a response to the API call.

The Api is exposed via HTTP.

When I try to read the messages from the API - it blocks waiting for 8k to be written to the stream. Is there a way to read less than 8k bytes at a time?

The read operation block here in java.net.SocketInputStream#socketRead0 because java.net.SocketInputStream#socketRead requests 8k bytes.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myapi/**")
public class MyApi {
private static Logger logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiController.class);

    private Queue<Byte[]> out = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
    private AtomicLong nextId = new AtomicLong();

    public MyApi() {
        new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            final long next = nextId.incrementAndGet();
            out.add(toObjectArray(Long.toString(next).getBytes()));
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public StreamingResponseBody download() {

        return outputStream -> {

            while (true) {
                if (out.isEmpty()) {
                    outputStream.write(1);
                    outputStream.write(new byte[]{0});
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        logger.error("Unexpected Error", e);
                    }
                } else {
                    final Byte[] msg = out.poll();
                    outputStream.write(msg.length);
                    outputStream.write(toPrimitiveArray(msg));
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private byte[] toPrimitiveArray(Byte[] bytes) {
        byte[] primitive = new byte[bytes.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            primitive[i] = bytes[i];
        }
        return primitive;
    }

    private Byte[] toObjectArray(byte[] bytes) {
        Byte[] primitive = new Byte[bytes.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            primitive[i] = bytes[i];
        }
        return primitive;
    }
}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/myapi/download");
    InputStream stream = url.openStream();

    int length = stream.read();

    while (length != -1) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            bytes[i] = (byte)stream.read();
        }
        System.out.println(Long.valueOf(new String(bytes)));
        length = stream.read();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Call `outputStream.flush()`?

Comment: Surprisingly (to me :) ) your suggestion works! Thank you. I'm puzzled as to why though.

Comment: Because the `OutputStream` is buffering the output. Calling `flush()` dumps the data to the underlying media (in this case a socket). Without the call to `flush()` you are just filling up the output buffer until it reaches its automatic flushing threshold. A packet capture should show you that nothing is being sent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clear explanation. If you want to put that into an answer - I'll accept it as the solution to my question.

Comment: I'm good. If someone else wants to do so they may.